# apply an external css file to a scoped div tag?

Tags: html, css

I have a main css file for the whole site called StyleSheetMain.css. I download a slider that has his own style.css file and there is a conflict on some items.I want to scope the slider's css file only to a div that it will contains only the slider items.I dont want to apply this css outside the slider div.
Any idea?thanksss

Comment: rename your classes so they dont conflict with the slider one or make use of how Nikko targeted specific items using CSS Targeting

Comment: For trivia's sake: http://html5doctor.com/the-scoped-attribute/. But 1) this is [barely supported by anyone](http://caniuse.com/#search=scoped) 2) I'm having trouble finding much documentation on acceptance and 3) if you have control over the styles and/or markup, there are plenty of capabilities within CSS to select only the elements you want. Even if this attribute is implemented someday, it would rarely be the best option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as **scope** in CSS. You can't nest a specific chunk of CSS in other CSS. **The below code is WRONG and is just an example of what you CAN'T DO.**

```
.some-class {
    /* THIS */
    .some-minor-class {
        /* IS */
    }
    /* WRONG */
}
```

You also can't point certain `.css` file to work in only a part of html.

Your solution is simple - **rename your classes**.

> *There are so many words to describe this world we live in*

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of CSS Grouping / Nesting.

for example you have:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="slider">
    </div>
</div>

<div id="newslider">
    <div id="slider">
    </div>
</div>
```

for you to change the style for the second slider:

```
#newslider #slider {
   background: #fff;
}
```